# Whats the best way to make use of a counter variable in this nested 'map' loop so that each square key or value incremenents up from 1 to 9

Tags: reactjs

```
    return (
    <div>
        <div className="board">
        {
            [1,2,3].map( (row) => {
                    return <div key={row} className="board-row">
                {
                    [1,2,3].map( (col) => {
                        return <Square key={col}></Square>
                    })
                }
                </div>

            })
        }
        </div>
    </div>
  );
```

How might i make it so the Squares generated by this nested for loop (using array map functions) could use a counter so that the square's value would be 0 to 8 or 1 to 9.

I am struggling to create a variable outside of these javascript arrow functions...

(I have a Java background and am struggling i little wrapping my head around javascript/react :) )

Many thanks for any help/direction.

John

EDIT:

Below is solution that worked for me in the end!

{

```
            [1,2,3].map( (row) => {
                    return <div key={row} className="board-row">
                {
                    [1,2,3].map( (col) => {
                        return this.renderSquare(++count);
                    })
                }
                </div>

            })
        }
        </div>
```

Here is renderSquare function also:

renderSquare(i) {
return (
<Square
value={this.props.squares[i]}
onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}
key = {i}
/>
);
}

I think a lot of the confusion is because of JSX and learning how and when you can type HTML and/or JavaScript where.

FINAL EDIT:
please note, i changed from ++count to count++ to avoid the initial increment occurring too early.  Doing this breaks the calculateWinner logic, just if anyone else is doing the tic tac toe tutorial! :)

Comment: Coming from Java, my thinking looking at this was to declare an Int outside of both 'For loops' then increment within the second 'for loop' the counter as this is the area where that counter will iterate 9 times and that will give each of the squares a unique number for its key and value.  However every attempt here with react disallows this.   Is this the best way to think about this problem or is there a better way to approach this.

Comment: Do you want to increment and output a counter each time the second loop is called?

Comment: Instead of `return <Square key={col}></Square>`, try `return <Square key={col}>{col + (row-1)*3}</Square>` & it should get you 1, 2, 3...9. If you need o..8, simply subtract one like so: `{col - 1 + (row-1) * 3}`. Tip: For 4x4 tables, use `(row-1) * 4`, in general for nxn, use `(row - 1) * n`. For tables like 3 x 4 or 4 x 3, the same idea may be modified to account for different row & col values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to count and output the number of times the second loop is called then the following is a solution to it:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Test2() {
  let count = 0;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Test 1 Component</h1>
      {[1, 2, 3].map((row) => {
        return (
          <div key={row}>
            {[1, 2, 3].map((col) => {
              return <div key={col}>{++count}</div>;
            })}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```